# Detecting and suppressing REINSTALLMODE=v switch

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3

**Summary:**: *is it possible to detect REINSTALLMODE=v switch (passed to the msiexec) from within the WiX script code and disable it?*

**Story.**

Our software has been using auto-updates delivered with MSI minor upgrades (downloaded automatically and invoked as REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus). This was version 1.x.

Obviously, minor upgrades have quite a few limitations, so recently we've cleaned up the whole automated deployment and update process. In version 2.x we are using auto-generated MSI packages with major upgrades (as recommended by WiX3). All updates work flawlessly when upgrading between 2.x versions.

Yet, when user at 1.x is updated to 2.x, nothing really happens, because of that v switch that is passed to the msiexec. Is it possible to suppress it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe so. The "v" switch tells the Windows Installer to recache the MSI and the Windows Installer does that very early in the process.